# Chinese remainder theorem unique solution

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

If I have two equations such that

$$X\equiv a \pmod b\\
X\equiv c \pmod d$$

I can use linear Diophantine Equations to find multiple solutions to X.
Can I find multiple solutions using CRT.

what if I have a third equation
$$X\equiv e \pmod g$$

How do I find multiple possible solutions (note: I can find one solution using CRT)

Comment: Assuming $(b,d)=1$, you get a solution $X\pmod{bd}$ which is already an infinite set of solutions, and it includes all of the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $b,d$ are coprime you can find *all* solutions using CRT, because according to it they are all congruent to each other modulo the product  $bd$. In other words, if $s$ is one solution you know how to find every other one is of the form $s+t\,bd$ for some integer $t$. The same works for three or any number of coprime moduli.

If they are not coprime there may be no solutions at all, but if one $s$ exists then every other one is of the form $s+t\,\text{lcm}[b,d]$, where $\text{lcm}$ is the least common multiple, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).